# C# CSV Parsing- how to get correct format from string (date) representation?

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I am parsing a CSV file. One of it's columns represents a date. The thing is that the date can be in dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy.

I can't identify which format is correct when for example the date there is 06/04/2015 (April or June?)

My code is doing this to format the output (standarized csv) when I can tell the difference. Do you know if there is a better method to this and how to Identify correct format?

```
  public static DateTime? ToValidDateTime(this string date)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            return null;

        try
        {
            var r = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            return new DateTime(r.Year, r.Month, r.Day, r.Hour, r.Minute, r.Second);


        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            var r = DateTime.Parse(date);

            return new DateTime(r.Year, r.Month, r.Day, r.Hour, r.Minute, r.Second);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you can't tell what format the date is in, how do you expect a computer to do so? If the date is ambiguous, it will need a well-defined date format to parse the date. Also note that DateTime is a struct, so there is absolutely no reason to copy the result of the parse into a new datetime, you can just return the result of the parse directly.

Comment: is there another column which includes something like a Location that you can use to determine the culture?

Comment: It is unclear what your actual question about. If you wondering how can you determine is `06/04/2015` April or June - then generally you can't determine it without having additional information. If you just looking for a way to parse string having two formats - there is more elegant way with `ParseExact` and array of format strings as argument. But definitely it will not solve "April or June" problem.

Comment: There is no solution for this. You **MUST** fix the source data to use a set of formats that will not be amibiguos, or to include information that indicates which format to use.

Comment: Just confirm with the source to see if they are using US style or the rest of the world style :).  If it varies inside each row, then hopefully there is a way to determine what locality it's coming from, i.e. maybe address. If US, assume m/d/y else, assume d/m/y. Caveat... From dealing with dates so far, Canada seems to be one of the odd ducks since they do both which is a pain.  If possible, ask the source to output ISO date yyyy-mm-dd which is the best.

Comment: Thank you guys! the thing is that is non deterministic... each row might have it's own format, I can tell when the date is invalid however on this other case now I can see that is impossible. Thanks!

Comment: @JimmyChandra More than just US uses m/d/y. It's also used in Canada, Philippines, and a few smaller nations.

Comment: Yeah I know, I deal with extracting dates from invoices from all different places at the moment, seen a lot of whacky formats that you would probably haven't encounter regularly, lol :).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but it needs too much formating to fit as a comment. This code is redundant:

```
var r = DateTime.Parse(date);

return new DateTime(r.Year, r.Month, r.Day, r.Hour, r.Minute, r.Second);
```

You're creating two datetime instances for no good reason. Just the first one is good enough. You can just do this instead:

```
return DateTime.Parse(date);
```

The same holds for the version with the `InvariantCulture` format specifier.

Comment: Very reasonable - but ask yourself: "Does it answers OP quiestion?". So this should be a comment, I suppose.

Comment: ... as @Joel said in the first line of his comment-answer

Comment: @DrKoch well, technically he said it *after* my comment was posted. ;)